# Submit form to different host in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-submit, hidden-field

I have an Action Link implemented in my Razor view as below

```
<input type="hidden" id="format"/>

@Html.ActionLink("Save", "SaveFile", "ExportService", "http", "hrmsapp.mysystem.com", "", new { fileformat = <hidden field value here> }, new { @id = "save" })
```

I need to pass the value of hidden field to this action link in parameter "fileformat".

I could not find any way to do this. There are numerous threads talking about @using Html.Form with "post" method. However, I am not sure how to use form to post when I am having different domain hrms.mysystem.com. There is no overload in Html.Form for this purpose.

Is there any way to read the hidden field value in the action link code itself (without using form)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form action="http://hrmsapp.mysystem.com" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="format" name="fileformat" />
    <input type="submit" value="POST to HRMS app" />
</form>
```

All @Html.Form does is print up HTML. You don't have to use it. You can just hard-code the HTML form with the action pointing to a different server, and post it.

Comment: Yes you'r right! In this case, where to pass the controller and action names? Also, in your example, there is action attribute mentioned twice. I guess it's method instead of action?

Comment: If this is inter-server, you can not generate a path based on controller and action name as one ASP.NET application doesn't know the structure of the other. It will only see the layer before everything is routed, just like you would on a browser. You will have to hard code the complete path unfortunatly.

Comment: @AnilSoman, sorry the second action should have been `method`. I have updated the answer. As for the controller / action, Pluc is correct. You have to hard-code the full URL, including the protocol.

Comment: @danludwig: That's cool. It worked! Thanks a lot. :)
Pluc - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to replace a placeholder string:

```
<input type="hidden" id="format"/>

@Html.ActionLink("Save", "SaveFile", "ExportService", "http", "hrmsapp.mysystem.com", "", new { fileformat = "xxfileformat" }, new { @id = "save" })

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#save').attr('href', $('#save').attr('href').replace('xxfileformat', $('#format').val()))
    });
</script>
```